# Trying to make a script that takes first word from a txt file, writes it, repeat till all words written

Tags: autohotkey

I have a text file, it has several lines. 1 line = 1 word

Now I want a script, if I press a specific button it will write the first word (first line). If I press the button again, the next word will be written, it goes like that till all words are written. I have tried to code it but it will only write the first word and will keep writing it.. It won't take next word and I don't know why because actually I have made a variable that increases...

Here is my code:

```ahk
F11::

Index = 1
Array := Object()
Loop, Read, C:\Users\Emilia\Desktop\list.txt
{
    Array.Push(A_LoopReadLine)
}
Send % Array[Index]
Index++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [FileReadLine](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileReadLine.htm) with a line number parameter
2. Keep the index variable outside in the global context so it doesn't get reset to 1 each time
3. Use [SendPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) to send the word at once, not character-by-character.
   You can switch the default send mode with [`SendMode play`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm) command.
4. Send <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the end by adding `{Enter}` in the send command.

```ahk
index = 1
F11::
    FileReadLine line, C:\Users\Emilia\Desktop\list.txt, index
    SendPlay %line%{Enter}
    index++
    Return
```

Comment: Hey thankss!! How do I get to my list.txt with your code? The directory is C:\Users\Emilia\Desktop\list.txt. I have replaced your r:\1.ahk with it but nothing happens.

Comment: This code works for me in AutoHotkey 1.1.24.04. You can doubleclick the green AHK tray icon in the bottom right corner of the screen and see what code was executed. Try also with `Send` instead of `SendPlay`.